# Python - very confused about method and while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this method:

```
def is_active(self):
    if self.is_current_node():
        return True
    cur_children = self.get_children()
    while cur_children is not None:
        for child in cur_children:
            if child.is_current_node():
                return True
            raise Exception(child.display_name)
        cur_children = cur_children.get_children()
    return False
```

I put this method together and I put the `raise Exception(child.display_name)` to test out and "alert()" me to which child was being hit. The exception is never raised. You'd think that was because the function returned `True` on the `if child.is_current_node()` part. Well, if I replace the `if` part with this:

```
        for child in cur_children:
            if child.is_current_node():
                raise Exception(child.display_name)
```

It doesn't raise the exception still. If I do this however:

```
        for child in cur_children:
            raise Exception(child.display_name)
```

The exception is raised. I'm so confused. I'm sure this is something ridiculous but I was up till 2 and I can't think straight enough to wrap my tiny brain around this.

Comment: what's in the `is_current_node` method?

Comment: It just checks a static value against `self._url` and returns the comparison as a Boolean.

Comment: @Eric - shouldn't the exception be raised always in one of the first two versions? The second one says, `if True: raise` and don't return from the function. The first one says `raise` if none of the `if True:` return from the function.

Comment: @aaronasterling - If that's the case, why wouldn't the first version always raise the exception? The first one essentially says, "For each: if True: return; raise;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

cur_children = self._children
    while cur_children is not None:
        for child in cur_children:
            if child.is_current_node():
                return True
            raise Exception(child.display_name)
        cur_children = cur_children._children

I assume that `self._children` contains multiple children: `[A, B, C]`

Then, on the first loop, it will take `A`. Let's assume that `A` has these children: `[AA, AB, AC`].

Now, you do this: `cur_children = cur_children._children`. This means that now, instead of continuing with `B` from the inital `[A, B, C]`, it will continue with `AA`, and so on.

In this example, it will never reach `B`. Is this intended?

---

What does your `is_current_node()` contains? Probably you forgot to return a value, so the result is always `None`, and `bool(None) == False`.

---

Another idea: (recursion)

```
def is_active(self):

    def check_children(children):
        for child in children:
            if child.is_current_node():
                return True
            else:
                if children._children:
                    return check_children(children._children)
        return False

    if self.is_current_node():
        return True
    return check_children(children)
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is `children` defined or passed into the function in your example? Did you mean: `return check_children(self.children)`, or am I missing something? For some reason tree traversal is so confusing to me.

Answer (score 2):

If the first child in the list .is_current_node(), then the exception will never be raised in your first snippet.

Everything you have for evidence is supporting the idea that either self.is_current_node() is always true, or the first scanned child .is_current_node(). Given the third code snippet, the latter seems to be the case.

EDIT: removing a misunderstanding (child != self) :/

Actually, I have to ask, what is this supposed to do? It looks vaguely like recursive tree-traversal, but it's not quite there. (the cur_children = cur_children.get_children() line in particular is a bit strange)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is_current_node always returns True and is_current_tab always returns False? I think more context is needed to give you an answer.

The only thing I can think of is that is_current_node changes state.

Comment: Ooops, see my edit. I changed the names while I was editing. Sorry, they're both the same function.